# How does shrinking of tempdb log file work?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, shrink

On the following documentation page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-tempdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16

It states that:

> Assume that tempdb has two files: the primary data file (tempdb.mdf) that is 1024 MB and the log file (tempdb.ldf) that is 360 MB. Assume that sp_spaceused reports that the primary data file contains 600 MB of data. Also, assume that you want to shrink the primary data file to 800 MB. Calculate the desired percentage of free space left after the shrink: 800 MB - 600 MB = 200 MB. Now, divide 200 MB by 800 MB = 25 percent, and that is your target_percent. The transaction log file is shrunk accordingly, leaving 25 percent or 200 MB of space free after the database is shrunk.

I don't quite understand the last sentence. **The transaction log file is shrunk accordingly, leaving 25 percent or 200 MB of space free after the database is shrunk.**

"*25 percent or 200 MB of space*", these two numbers all come from the tempdb data file. Does that mean we don't need to consider how full the tempdb log file is when we are shrinking the tempdb log file and we only need to consider the data file?